# Webstorm doesn't see Meteor packages

Tags: meteor, webstorm

I have Webstorm 11.0.1 and Meteor 1.2.1.

I have an issue with Kadira:flow-router not being shown in external libraries and therefore Webstorm is painting red all the references to the FlowRouter API.

The Meteor app itself is working fine. The problem is with IDE only.

There was a similar issue with another API:
[Webstorm doesn't see API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888412/webstorm-doesnt-see-api)
However I was able to use the a o3 package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug of Meteor import system in WebStorm. The problem will be fixed in WS 11.0.2.

As workaround you can manually create external library for the directory:
"$USER_HOME/.meteor/packages/kadira_flow-router/2.9.0/web.browser".

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
What would be the equivalent for Windows?
I have a folder under:
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\kadira_flow-router\2.9.0\web.browser